# How to map LPC FMC pins to FPGA pins on a Zedboard?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

How to map fpga pins to actual physical pins on the FMC connector on a Zedboard?

Of course I have looked into the user's hardware guide and the master constraint file, but all I have found is a list of the FMC pins out on the FPGA side but nothing on how it is mapped to the LPC FMC pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. To the googlers out there, though there is no table, you can find this info on the schematics. Check the schematic of the FMC on:

http://zedboard.org/sites/default/files/documentations/ZedBoard_RevD.2_Schematic_130516.pdf

and match the labels with the UCF file.